# How are mouse events delivered to widgets in QT

Tags: c++, qt

Consider this situation:

For a button on a widget: if there is a chance that the button's `clicked()` slot is delivered (processed) after the widget (that contains the button) gets hided by explicitly calling `hide()`?

For instance, suppose that there is a timer, and in its `timeout()` slot, `widget.hide()` gets called. Coincidentally, The user clicks the button just at the same time time is up.

The question is: Is there a chance that the button's `clicked()` slot get called after timer's `timeout()` slot (which hides the widget that contains the button)?

Answer (score 1):

No, the main thread in synchronous respect the GUI actions, so you cannot change the visibility of an object living in the main thread (like your `QPushButton`) exactly at the same time an user is clicking on it. Also, unless you 're on a multithread app with different events loops, your `QTimer` will be processed in the main thread too, so it is synchronous respect the UI. In few words: you may get a *millisecond concurrence* (clicking immediately before hiding it), but not actual parallelism.

If you care about this, maybe you can set a small delay before actually processing the click, just to check if the button was clicked but immediately hidden. In this case you can ignore the user input but it would be confusing. Another option would be to delay hiding the button if it was clicked, so the user doesn't get the wrong visual feedback.

Comment: Thank you @cbuchart, I think I know the mechanism behind: In short, the mouse click events are only delivered to the top visible widget by default. In my case, after `hide()` in `timeout()`, the widget becomes invisible (although may still be seen, as it has not been repainted), therefore the mouse events ignore this widget (and its children) and delivered to the widget behind it (to check its visibility and other states) and so on.

Comment: That's correct, the mouse handling event occurs on the underlying (actual) layout of widgets, the current rendering on-screen is not related at all and can be out-of-date. Sometimes I find useful to `qApp->processEvents()` in order to flush the pending events (including repainting) and keep the UI as updated as possible.

Comment: Yes, `qApp->processEvents()` seems to be an entry for processing all pending events, including paint events. However, I have never used it like that because I think it breaks the built-in event loop and may cause unpredictable program flow, such as one button's `clicked()` slot may nest in another one's.